# Hyperledger Fabric failed to update block with no error response

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I started a network 3 days ago and everything works perfectly. After 2 days, I tried again but it failed functioning. The strange part is that it fails to produce any error function. I used 4 methods to do transaction in the network and all responded success.

I would be much appreciated if someone can guide me what potentially could happen. Thank you in advance.

```
composer participant add --card admin@network -d '{ JSON }'
Result: Command succeeded

playground (add participant / do transaction)
Result: add participant flashed but nothing added / Do transaction on top right hand corner returns a success message with a transaction ID returned.

localhost/3000/explorer (do transaction)
Result: Response body: return with a transaction ID / Response Code: 200

curl transaction
Result: Response body: return with a transaction ID and proper response body
```

Moreover, there is no transaction found in the "Transaction" section of playground.

I tried to use "composer network reset".
I tried to bring down playground to restart.
I tried to bring down rest-server and restart.
None of above can fix.

Version used:

```
composer v0.20.0
Environment name and version (e.g. Chrome 39, node.js 5.4): node.js v8.11.3
Operating System and version (desktop or mobile): descktop
```

Docker image
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES

```
670352d9f16f        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-ebl-0.0.2-048894bc5223f0614cf7d36d26842b11e90182c5c27528e31109efd98d3c57f9   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   3 days ago          Up 3 days                                                            dev-peer0.org1.example.com-ebl-0.0.2
a9f60d553990        hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.0                                                                           "peer node start"        3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
8bb3111c7430        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.0                                                                        "orderer"                3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
6d8eec017b95        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.10                                                                       "tini -- /docker-ent…"   3 days ago          Up 3 days           4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
29c5b98d440a        hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.2.0                                                                             "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
```

Log:
Log of adding participant:
An error of "Noun does not match" seems to be the issue.

```
2018-09-12T02:52:19.334Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :matchRule()               > Resource {id=org.hyperledger.composer.system.TransactionRegistry#org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant}, READ, {"$class":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin","participantId":"admin"}, {"$class":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant","resources":[{"$class":"tech.threehundredcubits.eBL.Shipper","entityId":"Esprit","entityName":"Esprit","email":"o@hingjlee.net","address":{"$class":"tech.threehundredcubits.eBL.Address","country":"UK"}}],"targetRegistry":"resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.ParticipantRegistry#tech.threehundredcubits.eBL.Shipper","transactionId":"a2fbd509e36b4a68658c411f8e0504088cb4db2e6e18ae1db70827f5c3e3e07f","timestamp":"2018-09-12T02:52:19.249Z"}, [object Object]
2018-09-12T02:52:19.334Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :matchVerb()               > READ, [object Object]
2018-09-12T02:52:19.334Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :matchVerb()               < true
2018-09-12T02:52:19.334Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :matchNoun()               > org.hyperledger.composer.system.TransactionRegistry#org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant, [object Object]
2018-09-12T02:52:19.335Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :matchNoun()               < false
2018-09-12T02:52:19.335Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :matchRule()               Noun does not match
2018-09-12T02:52:19.335Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :matchRule()               < false
2018-09-12T02:52:19.335Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :Processing rule SystemACL undefined
2018-09-12T02:52:19.335Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :Processing rule NetworkAd undefined
2018-09-12T02:52:19.335Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :AccessController         :check()                   Processing rule [object Object]
```

Log of Historian registry:

```
2018-09-12T02:52:19.470Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :EngineTransactions       :submitTransaction()       Storing Historian record in Historian registry
2018-09-12T02:52:19.470Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :NodeDataCollection       :add()                     > a2fbd509e36b4a68658c411f8e0504088cb4db2e6e18ae1db70827f5c3e3e07f, {"$class":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord","transactionId":"a2fbd509e36b4a68658c411f8e0504088cb4db2e6e18ae1db70827f5c3e3e07f","transactionType":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant","transactionInvoked":"resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant#a2fbd509e36b4a68658c411f8e0504088cb4db2e6e18ae1db70827f5c3e3e07f","participantInvoking":"resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin","identityUsed":"resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#2d8025bade10a43df0b65b79b9b2ea4f47f6679ea9453a4d7f7e00dca53b31ff","eventsEmitted":[],"transactionTimestamp":"2018-09-12T02:52:19.249Z","$registryType":"Asset","$registryId":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"}, false
2018-09-12T02:52:19.474Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :NodeDataCollection       :add()                     <
2018-09-12T02:52:19.474Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :NodeDataCollection       :@PERF add()               Total (ms) duration: 4.00
2018-09-12T02:52:19.475Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :TransactionLogger        :onResourceAdded()         > {"registry":{"type":"Asset","id":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord","name":"Asset registry for org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"},"resource":{"$class":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord","transactionId":"a2fbd509e36b4a68658c411f8e0504088cb4db2e6e18ae1db70827f5c3e3e07f","transactionType":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant","transactionInvoked":"resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant#a2fbd509e36b4a68658c411f8e0504088cb4db2e6e18ae1db70827f5c3e3e07f","participantInvoking":"resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin","identityUsed":"resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#2d8025bade10a43df0b65b79b9b2ea4f47f6679ea9453a4d7f7e00dca53b31ff","eventsEmitted":[],"transactionTimestamp":"2018-09-12T02:52:19.249Z"}}
2018-09-12T02:52:19.475Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :TransactionLogger        :onResourceAdded()         <
2018-09-12T02:52:19.475Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :EngineTransactions       :submitTransaction()       <
2018-09-12T02:52:19.475Z [a2fbd509] DEBUG    :EngineTransactions       :@PERF submitTransaction() Total (ms) duration: 157.00
```

Comment: As per rocket chat chat response - I wonder if you have implemented ACLs that are preventing you seeing the data, and the historian records. Perhaps repeating your tests with a more permissive ACL would be a useful test.

Comment: The fact that it was working then after a day stopped working might mean you have a time skew issue. Need to look for information about this in the peer logs

Comment: I built another instance from scratch and try to recreate the scene. In building the new instance, I deployed in addition to the original network, I also deployed 1 very basic network without ACL and the original network without ACL control. I then did transactions in basic network and it worked out fine. After that, I did transactions in original network (without ACL) and it still crashed whole fabric. I haven't even tried to do transaction in the original network with ACL in place to recreate the scene.

Comment: The error is gone after I switched from Fabric v1.2 to v1.1 and Composer v0.20.0 to v0.19.14 (and v0.19.15). The error is likely caused by Fabric v1.2. Will start another thread in Fabric forum.